# recoding data in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

All,

I have a time series of data that is hourly.  See below:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00     96.8 
2014-01-01 01:00:00     91.3 
2014-01-01 02:00:00     97.8 
2014-01-01 03:00:00     77.0
2014-01-01 04:00:00    132.7
2014-01-01 05:00:00    188.1
2014-01-01 06:00:00    141.1
2014-01-01 07:00:00    115.5
```

I would to wrangle this into a DataFrame that looks like this:

Month  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  ... 
Jan
Feb                     Data
Mar
...

What is the best way to do this in python pandas?  The data in the series is pre formmatted and the index is a datetime. Here is the index:

```
class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex' 
[2014-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2014-12-31 23:00:00] 
Length: 8760, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Have a look at Pandas `pivot_table`. Your question is very vague, what kind of answer do you expect? You don't specify whats on axis 1 and how the data should be handled/aggregated.

Comment: Ok.  I will take a look at that.  Basically, what I have is a series of hourly data -- each hour in a year has it's own value. I would like to group that by summing the value for each hour value in a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly it looks like you want to resample your data by summing the hourly values over a monthly time period. You can do that using [pandas resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function:

```
# This will resample your data by month.
df.resample('1M').sum()
```